# (node:2880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: cloud9-ide

I am using Cloud9 and am trying to run the following code:

```
var bodyParser  = require("body-parser"),
mongoose        = require("mongoose")
express         = require("express"),
app             = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/restful_blog_app");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
// title
// image
// body
// created



app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING!");
})
```

I go start up the server and am getting the following:

(node:2880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

Answer (score 0):

Hey don't know if you're still looking for answer on this one, but I would try restarting the Mongodb server again by using "cd" in the terminal to get to the your root directory then running "./mongod"

Hope that helps.

-
Wes jones.